# A question about Kotlin extension functions resolution

Tags: kotlin

The code below :

```kotlin
package experimental

import experimental.AnObject.f

interface AnInterface {
    fun String.a() = "[AnInterface] $this"
}

object AnObject {
    fun AnInterface.f(str: String) = "[AnObject]" + str.a()
}

class AnInterfaceImpl  : AnInterface

fun main() {
    println( AnInterfaceImpl().f("hi") ) 
}
```

prints `[AnObject][AnInterface] hi`

My question is, how does the call to `AnInterfaceImpl().f` ends up resolved to the
extension function in `AnObject`

Comment: Check this out -- https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-do-extension-functions-work/609

Comment: You can also read [Kotlin Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions)

Comment: Since extensions are statically resolved, when you add `f()` to `AnInterface`, it is available to it's inherited classes as well. Also, you don't even need to wrap it in `AnObject`.

Comment: "How does the call to AnInterfaceImpl().f ends up resolved to the extension function in AnObject" -- Important to note here is that, the extension is not resolved to `AnObject`, it is still resolved to `AnInterface`.